# enabling a submit button after an mvc post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using .Net MVC 4.

I have two buttons on one View wrapped around two separate Html.BeginForm statements. The first one is visibile and the second one is not (it depends if the first button logic after the post is successfull).

How can I make visibile the second button after the first button pressed goes into the Controller method? The method basically says, I'm OK, now I can make visible the second button. I'm passing back a View. Is there a viewbag variable (or something of the sort) I can set that once I get back into the View, I can make that second button visisble?

The second button is just an input button with an Id value.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a viewbag variable (or something of the sort) I can set that
>   once I get back into the View, I can make that second button visisble?

Yeah but since I am not a big fan of ViewBag I would suggest you adding a boolean property to your model and then set this property in the POST controller action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    model.IsSecondButtonVisible = true;
    return View(model);
}
```

and then inside the view:

```
@if (Model.IsSecondButtonVisible)
{
    <input type="button" value="the second button" />
}
```

Comment: This sounds great, but the first button is initially set to invisible. When I'm coing back from into the View, looks like I'll need to set some kind of html attribute (based on whether the button should be visibile my your model property) that says to make the button visible. How would I accomplish that???

Answer (score 1):

First Method: As explained above, but I am afraid, it will not work if for example you have a partial view and based on something there you want to show or hide something.

Second Method:Initial Page load, button is visible.

```
<input id='btnAdd' type='button' value='Add' style='display:block;'/>
```

Based on some action on page/partial view

```
<script>
  function disableAdd() {
  $('#btnAdd').hide();
}
</script>
```

*Please note, jquery will not be able to hide/show if you use visibility in style sheet.